.NET Blazor WebAssembly ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED only on Mac devices
I have 2 projects, one being .NET Core Web API and a Blazor WebAssembly App.
Currently I have ONLY Mac users getting an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when attempting to login using a username and password.

I am using HttpClientFactory POST to request the login on the App side
I have checked and tried the following:

Having the user clear his cache
Check that there is no Proxy
User is using a VPN (Not sure if this can cause the issue)


Hello FallenHero, could you kindly check why there are double /api in the request, now the request url is /api/api/login/get_access_token.

It's just an IIS setup the client did, we will be changing it down the line.

Okay, so Apple think they are smart and it basically their App Transport Security Settings were blocking the API. As the app in only internal there is no SSL Certs against the Web App on IIS
